# why can't I write element to a moved position in array in Rust, but I can do it in tuple

Tags: arrays, rust

I destruct an element from a tuple, and then write back a new element. It works.

```
  let mut a = ("111".to_string(), "222".to_string());
  let (b,_) = a;
  a.0 = "333".to_string();
  println!("{:?}", a);          //output:("333", "222")
```

But I can't do it in an array:

```
    let mut a = ["111".to_string(), "222".to_string()];
    let [b,_] = a;
    a[0] = "333".to_string();
    ^^^^ value used here after partial move
    println!("{:?}", a);
```

I don't why if a tuple is partial moved, I can use it again. But if an array is partial moved, I can't use it anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't why if a tuple is partial moved, I can use it again. But if an array is partial moved, I can't use it anymore.

Because `a[0] = ...` desugars to `*IndexMut::index_mut(&mut a, 0) = ...`, and that requires `a` to be "whole", because the compiler doesn't peer through functions to see whether partially moved structures are OK (the compiler understands partial moves but they're not part of the type system).

`a.0` is setting a field on a struct, so the compiler understands the entire operation and that it "fills" the partially moved structure back to a valid one.

Note how if you remove the `a.0 = "333".to_string();` statement you can't print the tuple anymore, because it's not complete anymore. However you can print `a.1`. Not so with the array, once you've partially moved it, `a[1]` is also invalid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. So the key point is the array ```a``` is a whole thing. Compiler needs to call the ```index_mut``` method on it to write an element. But the tuple's element can be accessed directly by the dot operator.

Comment: Well it's less the array "being a whole thing", so is a tuple, the issue is the requirements of what you're accessing. You can't e.g. call `a.clone()` on the partially moved tuple either. But field access of a struct (which is what a tuple is) is a very direct and low level operation, it's not "hidden" from the compiler, and thus the compiler can be lenient. I'm actually surprised you can "fix up" a partially moved struct, I've never even attempted that.

Comment: Note that technically speaking, array indexing is an intrinsic and does not desugar to `IndexMut`.